# MySQL get dates for drawing barchart

Tags: mysql, sql, time-series, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to pull all information inside a given date range from my database using something like this query:

```
SELECT transactionDate, SUM(transactionTotal) 
  FROM transaction
 WHERE transactionDate BETWEEN '2014-06-01' AND '2014-08-11'
  AND transactionType = 'end'
GROUP BY DAYOFMONTH(transactionDate)
ORDER BY transactionDate ASC
```

But somehow I only get the data for 1 month

```
2014-06-01 20:38:05 4811500.00
2014-06-02 20:42:59 5924950.00
2014-06-03 20:44:38 3811500.00
2014-06-04 11:45:13 4472000.00
2014-06-05 15:34:53 7922000.00
2014-06-06 17:45:28 5027000.00
2014-06-07 11:25:38 4378000.00
2014-06-08 07:59:04 4250000.00
2014-06-09 08:41:49 4766500.00
2014-06-10 01:23:35 4071000.00
2014-06-11 01:01:30 1459000.00
2014-06-12 15:05:08 2960000.00
2014-06-13 00:47:09 1160000.00
2014-06-14 16:52:20 4208000.00
2014-06-16 00:05:18 3947500.00
2014-06-17 00:18:39 4926000.00
2014-06-18 00:33:38 4244500.00
2014-06-19 00:43:39 4045000.00
2014-06-20 22:47:54 2649500.00
2014-06-21 23:06:04 4030000.00
2014-06-22 23:19:22 945500.00
2014-06-23 23:29:27 3015000.00
2014-06-24 23:35:56 2420000.00
2014-06-25 00:02:03 3920000.00
2014-06-26 00:50:33 4841000.00
2014-06-27 10:39:14 4095000.00
2014-06-28 07:43:06 5605500.00
2014-06-29 11:48:24 1939000.00
2014-06-30 10:49:50 3620000.00
```

As you can see, I get the results from 2014-06-01 to 2014-06-01 even when all other dates also have data to display.

Hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: You group by month but want to output every day? That does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misusing `GROUP BY` and the pernicious MySQL `GROUP BY` extension is biting you. You're grouping your data into 31 buckets with your `GROUP BY DAYOFMONTH()` , so there's no way you'll get more than 31 rows in your result set.  You're then (misusing the extension) displaying some arbitrarily selected  `transaction_date` value from each of your 31 groupings.  It happens to be a June date, and this has tricked you into thinking you've only selected June records. You've actually selected all the dates in your range, but mistakenly grouped July and August records with your June records. Ouch.

Second, using `BETWEEN` to select date ranges from a `DATETIME` column isn't quite right, because it gets the end of the range wrong.  `BETWEEN '2014-06-01' AND '2014-08-11'` gets the items dated from the first of June up until the very first moment of August 11th. So something happening at noon on August 11th won't get selected.

Here is the query you need to do this job correctly.

```
    SELECT DATE(transactionDate),
           SUM(transactionTotal) 
      FROM transaction 
     WHERE transactionDate >= '2014-06-01'
       AND transactionDate  < '2014-08-11' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
       AND transactionType = 'end'
  GROUP BY DATE(transactionDate) 
  ORDER BY DATE(transactionDate) ASC
```

What's going on here?  First, we're grouping by just the date of each transaction, using `DATE()`, and we're including that grouped value in our result set with `SELECT DATE()`.

Second, the date range selection takes everything on or after midnight on June first, up until the moment right before midnight on August 12th. That's the point of `transactionDate  < '2014-08-11' + INTERVAL 1 DAY`. It takes the whole day's worth of items for August 11.

There's a writeup of this corner of SQL tech here:  http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/sql-reporting-time-intervals/

Comment: Thanks @Ollie Jones, it works as expected now and I learned something very useful for my project. Thanks for the article too.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following sql query to get desired results

```
SELECT transactionDate, SUM(transactionTotal) FROM transaction WHERE transactionDate BETWEEN '2014-06-01' AND '2014-08-11' AND transactionType = 'end' GROUP BY CAST(transactionDate AS DATE) ORDER BY transactionDate ASC
```